# Deprecate a specific controller path name, when having more that one path names

Tags: java, spring

I have the following controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"oldoperation", "newoperation"})
@Api(description = "Operations", tags = {"operation-controller"})
public class OperationController {
```

With this setup, every method I have inside the controller, automatically appears under both paths. For example:

```
@GetMapping(path = "{id}")
public String getSomething() {
  // implementation
}
```

will work with both paths:

1. oldoperation/getSomething/{id}
2. newoperation/getSomething/{id}

Is there a way while maintaining both path names ("oldoperation", "newoperation"), to deprecate the "oldoperation" one? Meaning, either overlining it on swagger-ui or adding a description for its deprecation. And without adding each method 2 times, one for each path name.

Thank you